# in unity, my camera goes crazy when i move around as the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Whenever I am in unity, player mode, my camera works, when I am still, but when I move the player, the camera goes crazy.
Player movement code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private CharacterController controller;
    public float speed = 5.0f;

    public GameObject player; // Reference to the player GameObject

    void Start()
    {
        controller = player.GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (controller == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("CharacterController not found on the player GameObject.");
            return;
        }

        // Get input for movement in the horizontal and vertical directions
        float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        // Calculate the movement direction based on the input
        Vector3 inputDirection = new Vector3(horizontalInput, 0.0f, verticalInput);

        // Move the player
        Vector3 moveDirection = transform.TransformDirection(inputDirection) * speed;
        controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Camera look code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform player; // Reference to the player GameObject.
    public float sensitivity = 2.0f; // Mouse sensitivity.
    public Vector2 rotationLimits = new Vector2(-80, 80); // Vertical rotation limits.

    private float rotationX = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked; // Lock the cursor to the game window.
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Get mouse input.
        float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensitivity;
        float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensitivity;

        // Rotate the player horizontally based on mouse input.
        player.Rotate(Vector3.up * mouseX);

        // Calculate vertical rotation for the camera.
        rotationX -= mouseY;
        rotationX = Mathf.Clamp(rotationX, rotationLimits.x, rotationLimits.y);

        // Apply the rotation to the camera.
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(rotationX, 0, 0);
    }
}
```

I tried moving the camera, I expected it to work, but when I move it goes crazy. If I knew how to attach a video, I would show what I meant.

Comment: Why does a camera controller also move the player?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't multiple by `Time.deltaTime` for the mouseX and mouseY variables, so the movement is many times what it should be. Do that and it should work. Just make sure the sensitivity is set right as well.

As a rule of thumb, most movement you do per frame should be multiplied by deltaTime.